# Is it possible to have textbox as part of radio button values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

First timer. Please spare me some beatings.

I have a ridiculous request.

We have a set of radio buttons dynamically generated from sql server database.

For instance, there is a Questions table and one of the columns is ChoiceType.

ChoiceType has 3 values, S for single choice (Radio buttons); M for Mulitple choices (Checkboxes); and T for Textboxes.

Here is the markup:

Then codebehind snippet

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
  <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Columns="30" Font-Bold="False" Rows="5"
                                            TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
 </td>
</tr>

Protected Sub DataList1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles DataList1.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        Dim anstype As HiddenField = e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField1")
        'Dim questionid As Label = e.Item.FindControl("Label3")
        Dim questionid As HiddenField = e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField2")
        Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = e.Item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1")
        Dim cbl As CheckBoxList = e.Item.FindControl("CheckBoxList1")
        Dim txt As TextBox = e.Item.FindControl("TextBox1")
        Dim ds As DataSet = GetDataSet(questionid.Value)
        Select Case anstype.Value
            Case "S"
                rbl.Visible = True
                cbl.Visible = False
                txt.Visible = False
                rbl.DataSource = ds
                rbl.DataTextField = "Choice"
                rbl.DataValueField = "ChoiceID"
                rbl.DataBind()
            Case "M"
                rbl.Visible = False
                cbl.Visible = True
                txt.Visible = False
                cbl.DataSource = ds
                cbl.DataTextField = "Choice"
                cbl.DataValueField = "ChoiceID"
                cbl.DataBind()
            Case "T"
                rbl.Visible = False
                cbl.Visible = False
                txt.Visible = True
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

My question: Is it possible to present the textbox (T) as part of the RadiobuttonList options in such that all a user needs to do is check the box with the radio button with Textbox values and enter some text into the textbox?

Below is a screenshot to hopefully illustrate my point.

Sorry, Can post images right now.

Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need.

I am assuming that you are using datalist

```
<ItemTemplate>
<table>
  <tr>
 <td>
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
  <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Columns="30" Font-Bold="False" Rows="5"
                                            TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
 </td>
  <td>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxOptional" runat="server" Visible="false" Columns="30" Font-Bold="False" Rows="5" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Now in item databound, in case of M

```
 Case "M"
                rbl.Visible = False
                cbl.Visible = True
                txt.Visible = False
                cbl.DataSource = ds
                cbl.DataTextField = "Choice"
                cbl.DataValueField = "ChoiceID"
                cbl.DataBind()
    TextBoxOptional.Visible = true// assuming that you will find control on above lines.
```

Comment: sir, can you give me some example of how to do what you are suggesting?

Recall, I said these are dynamically generated from the database

Comment: sir I know how to create User Control. I am just not sure how it all fits into what I am trying to do. Sorry for my slow uptake.

Comment: I will like to integrate it with the itemDataBound sub I posted.

You sound like you know exactly what needs done.

I would really appreciate an example sir.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Tairoc, Can you pls make bit clear about your question what you want to do exactly..

Comment: @Kapil, let's say we have 5 radio button values, one is called `Through Advertisement`; another is called `Referred by Friend`; another is called `Search Engine`. The last one is called `Other`.

This one called `Other` should have a textbox. In other words, Other as well as Textbox to enter value for other.

Umarkashmiri, sorry sir I left out this bit by mistake.

Also, I put your textbox in S since S represents Radio button.

Comment: @UmarKashmiri, your code is almost working.

Just one more request and it should work fine. I want to say if radio button choice = "Other", in other words, if user checks the Other radio button then make TextBoxOptional Visible. After this change, it should be working.

Thank you very much sir for your patience. Thank you Stackoverflow.

Comment: @UmarKashmiri Sir, I requested just one more help. Please read my last post.

Comment: @Tairoc, you should accepted this as the answer and for another question or request you can make it as new question

Answer (score 0):

Put one text box with visible false and on radiobutton OnCheckedChanged event if the selected text of radiobutton is "Other" then make the textbox Visible True.

try this...

```
Protected Sub RadioButton1_OnCheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim RadioButton1 As RadioButton = TryCast(sender, RadioButton)
    Dim datalistrow As DataList = TryCast(RadioButton1.NamingContainer, DataList)
    Dim TxtOther As TextBox = TryCast(datalistrow.FindControl("TxtOther"), TextBox)
    TxtOther.Visible = True
End Sub 




<tr>
     <td>
      <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
      <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Columns="30" Font-Bold="False" Rows="5"
                                                TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
     </td>
  <td>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TxtOther" runat="server" Visible="False" Columns="30" Font-Bold="False" Rows="5"
                                                TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
  </td>
    </tr>

Protected Sub DataList1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles DataList1.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        Dim anstype As HiddenField = e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField1")
        'Dim questionid As Label = e.Item.FindControl("Label3")
        Dim questionid As HiddenField = e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField2")
        Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = e.Item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1")
        Dim cbl As CheckBoxList = e.Item.FindControl("CheckBoxList1")
        Dim txt As TextBox = e.Item.FindControl("TextBox1")
        Dim ds As DataSet = GetDataSet(questionid.Value)          

        Select Case anstype.Value
            Case "S"
                rbl.Visible = True
                cbl.Visible = False
                txt.Visible = False
                rbl.DataSource = ds
                rbl.DataTextField = "Choice"
                rbl.DataValueField = "ChoiceID"
                rbl.DataBind()
            Case "M"
                rbl.Visible = False
                cbl.Visible = True
                txt.Visible = False
                cbl.DataSource = ds
                cbl.DataTextField = "Choice"
                cbl.DataValueField = "ChoiceID"
                cbl.DataBind()
            Case "T"
                rbl.Visible = False
                cbl.Visible = False
                txt.Visible = True
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: great code but where is it checking if radio button selection is `Other`?

Comment: On load of Datalist if the radiobutton Selected option is "Other" you want to display TxtOther TextBox or After Loading the Datalist On Change of radiobutton to "Other"

Comment: Where you will get the Selection Value "Other" of Radiobutton to Compare in RowDatabound  event

Comment: you solution didn't fix the problem but that's ok. I will ask the question separately.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can check like this..

```
Protected Sub RadioButton1_OnCheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim RadioButton1 As RadioButtonList = TryCast(sender, RadioButtonList)
    If RadioButton1 IsNot Nothing Then
        If RadioButton1.SelectedValue = "Other" Then
            Dim datalistrow As DataList = TryCast(RadioButton1.NamingContainer, DataList)
            Dim TxtOther As TextBox = TryCast(datalistrow.FindControl("TxtOther"), TextBox)
            TxtOther.Visible = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```